# Django - Relationships in Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django there are field types called ForeignKey and OneToMany/OneToOne, I was wondering would I use ForeignKey or the relationship type as the field type in this scenario? User to Profile has been identified as OneToOne but I'm unsure about the others.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.DateField()
    address = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profilephoto = models.ImageField(default='default_profile.jpg', upload_to='reviewApp/static/profile_images')

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    releasedate = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()
    productphoto = models.ImageField(default='default_product.jpg', upload_to='reviewApp/static/product_images')

class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = model.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, validators = [MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    reviewtext = models.TextField()
    postdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    lastmodified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

[image: ERD for Project]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from what I see here, it seems to be good if the following is what you want:

- User can have only one profile and one Profile is related to only one user.
- a Profile can make multiple Review but a Review belongs to only one profile.
- A Product can have multiple Review but a Review is specific to one Product.

Be carefull to define the on_delete argument for your foreign keys depending of what you want to keep in your database after a delete.

More info from the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/fields/#arguments

Comment: That's exactly how I want it, thanks for your comment!

Comment: But if you want to have more than one profile to review the same product, you need to set profile and product to a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @joshlsullivan But wouldn't that be incorrect as one Review can only be linked to one Profile, whilst one Profile can have many Reviews?

Comment: @RajR96 I think I misread. I thought you wanted more than one profile to be able to create more than one review.